# How can I troubleshoot a very slow initial connection when web browsing on WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, browser, networking, dns, firewall

This has been bugging me for quite some time.

When connected to my home WiFi, web connections take a long time to initially establish (like ~10 seconds+) on two separate Android phones (OnePlus 3, and HTC 10). Once the connection is made, the download rates are absolutely fine. Also, web browsing is absolutely fine (almost no latency) on all other devices connected to the home WiFi - MacBook, PC (Windows and Linux). This issue is not observed on other WiFi networks, or when using mobile data.

I imagine it may be something to do with DNS resolution, firewall, or something else funny on my home router, but the main problem is I have no idea how to actually debug/troubleshoot this on an Android phone.

So by way of an answer, I would really appreciate either:

- Suggestions of tools for debugging something like this - something like the Developer Console in Chrome would be ideal
- Suggestions on what the underlying problem might be

Thanks alot

Comment: I'd suspect it might be some DNS or proxy settings that takes time to initiate. Have you considered sniffing the WiFi traffic between the Android device and the router, to see what's going on there?